# PHP Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied error

Tags: php, file-upload, zip

I found this code that takes a zip file and extract it. however I am running into some errors. When I try to upload a zip, i get this error `Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newLosani/testphp.php on line 26` I changed the permissions on the file and folder its going to 777 and 644, neither worked :(

I even tried to change the permissions of file I am uploading to 777 and that didnt work.

Here is the code in question:

```
<?php
if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
        $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
        $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
        $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

        $name = explode(".", $filename);
        $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
        foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
                if($mime_type == $type) {
                        $okay = true;
                        break;
                }
        }

        $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
        if(!$continue) {
                $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
        }

        $target_path = $filename;  // change this to the correct site path
        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $x = $zip->open($target_path);
                if ($x === true) {
                        $zip->extractTo("/zip/"); // change this to the correct site path
                        $zip->close();

                        unlink($target_path);
                }
                $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
        } else {
                $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
        }
        echo $message;
}
?>
```